# Alternative proofs that if $a_n \leqslant b_n$ then $\lim a_n \leqslant \lim b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

A well-known limit property asserts that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent sequences and $a_n \leqslant b_n$ for all $n$, then $\lim a_n \leqslant \lim b_n$.The most common means of proof is by contrapositive, but are there any other nice ways of proving this without using contrapositive?

Comment: Is this what you want: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lower_and_Upper_Bounds_for_Sequences/Corollary ?

Comment: No nice ways that I know of; but note that by considering $b_n-a_n$ and using that the limit of a difference is the difference of the limit, it's enough to show that if $0 \leq b_n$ then $0 \leq \lim b_n$.

Comment: I ask the question because I saw a nice proof a while ago involving a triangle inequality style argument, but I cannot remember the details.

Comment: I doubt the classical proof is by contradiction, it is rather by contrapositive.

Comment: Quite right, I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a_n \to A$ and $b_n \to B$.  We use the fact that $A \le B$ if and only if $A < B + \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.

There exists an index $n$ with the property that $|a_n - A| < \epsilon/2$ and $|b_n - B| < \epsilon/2$. Thus $$A < a_n + \epsilon/2 \le b_n + \epsilon/2 < B + \epsilon.$$

Thus $A \le B$.

Comment: I love that approach!